# abalone dataset low accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to practice on how to use estimators in tensorflow by using the abalone dataset. However, even though I tried different numbers of training steps , batch size, activation functions, learning rates and lays of networks the evaluation accuray is still around 20%. I tried the same structure with iris dataset and the accuracy is over 90%. I am wondering if the abalone dataset is not supposed to have high accuracy results? Or it should be trained using a different model other than DNN? My code is attached. Thank you very much!

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import tensorflow as tf

import Aba_data

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--batch_size', default=1000, type=int, help='batch size')
parser.add_argument('--train_steps', default=100000, type=int,
                help='number of training steps')

def my_model(features, labels, mode, params):
"""DNN with three hidden layers, and dropout of 0.1 probability."""
# Create three fully connected layers each layer having a dropout
# probability of 0.1.
net = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, params['feature_columns'])
for units in params['hidden_units']:
    net = tf.layers.dense(net, units=units, activation=tf.sigmoid)

# Compute logits (1 per class).
logits = tf.layers.dense(net, params['n_classes'], activation=None)

# Compute predictions.
predicted_classes = tf.argmax(logits, 1)
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    predictions = {
        'class_ids': predicted_classes[:, tf.newaxis],
        'probabilities': tf.nn.softmax(logits),
        'logits': logits,
    }
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions)

# Compute loss.
loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)

# Compute evaluation metrics.
accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels,
                               predictions=predicted_classes,
                               name='acc_op')
metrics = {'accuracy': accuracy}
tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy[1])

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=metrics)

# Create training op.
assert mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN

optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)


def main(argv):
args = parser.parse_args(argv[1:])

# Fetch the data
(train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y) = Aba_data.load_data(0.7)

# Feature columns describe how to use the input.
my_feature_columns = []
for key in train_x.keys():
    if key == 'Sex':
        my_feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.indicator_column(
            tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
                key=key, vocabulary_list=["M", "F", "I"])))
    else:
        my_feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key=key))

# Build 2 hidden layer DNN with 10, 10 units respectively.
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=my_model,
    params={
        'feature_columns': my_feature_columns,
        # Two hidden layers of 10 nodes each.
        'hidden_units': [10, 10],
        # The model must choose between 3 classes.
        'n_classes': 30,
    })

# Train the Model.
classifier.train(
    input_fn=lambda:Aba_data.train_input_fn(train_x, train_y, args.batch_size),
    steps=args.train_steps)

# Evaluate the model.
eval_result = classifier.evaluate(
    input_fn=lambda:Aba_data.eval_input_fn(test_x, test_y, args.batch_size))

print('\nTest set accuracy: {accuracy:0.3f}\n'.format(**eval_result))

# Generate predictions from the model
# expected = ['Setosa', 'Versicolor', 'Virginica']
# predict_x = {
#     'SepalLength': [5.1, 5.9, 6.9],
#     'SepalWidth': [3.3, 3.0, 3.1],
#     'PetalLength': [1.7, 4.2, 5.4],
#     'PetalWidth': [0.5, 1.5, 2.1],
# }
#
# predictions = classifier.predict(
#     input_fn=lambda:iris_data.eval_input_fn(predict_x,
#                                             labels=None,
#                                             batch_size=args.batch_size))
#
# for pred_dict, expec in zip(predictions, expected):
#     template = ('\nPrediction is "{}" ({:.1f}%), expected "{}"')
#
#     class_id = pred_dict['class_ids'][0]
#     probability = pred_dict['probabilities'][class_id]
#
#     print(template.format(iris_data.SPECIES[class_id],
#                           100 * probability, expec))


if __name__ == '__main__':
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
tf.app.run(main)
```

Comment: What are you trying to predict from what? There was [this competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/pred-411-2016-04-u3-abalone/leaderboard) on Kaggle in 2016 to count the number of rings, and the winner had a MSE of around 2. So roughly had an accuracy of +-2 for the number of rings. If that helps you place your network.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was using all other features to predict the age as classes (29 classes). I modified the estimator from iris, which predicts classes. Are you saying that this data set is supposed to be used to predict a continuous output rather than discrete ones? If I want to practice on discrete outputs, other than iris data, is there other dataset that you recommend? Thank you!

Comment: Well, not necessarily, but your metric is a bit harsh on yourself this way. Basically, if you're treat them as independent classes, and you predict 5 years of age, and the true age is 6 or 99, your loss will be the same. So for age it makes sense to use the square difference or similar as loss. Do you want something to do with abalones or are you looking for any dataset to practice classification?

Comment: Now that you've pointed that out, it makes much more sense! My eventual goal is to be able to predict a binary output (0 or 1) from 119 kinds of features, using 20k training samples. Therefore, I am in general looking for classification problems, if that is reasonable. Since my code is modified from the estimator for iris dataset, I want to use something different